# How to remove save and continue button in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I don't know how to remove save and continue button in Magento..

In construct other buttons are removing properly but save and continue button alone not removing..

I tried these codes

```
            $this->_removeButton('save_and_continue');
            $this->_removeButton('saveAndContinueEdit');
            $this->_removeButton('save_and_edit_button');
```

But not working..

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_controller = 'customer';


        parent::__construct();

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save Customer'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Delete Customer'));

        if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->isReadonly() ) {
            $this->_removeButton('save');
            $this->_removeButton('reset');
        }
        if (Mage::registry("new_job")) {
//            $this->_removeButton('save');
            $this->_updateButton('save_and_continue', 'class', 'new_job_save_btn');
//            $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save Customer and Add Job'));
            $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save And Exit'));

            $this->_removeButton('reset');
            $this->_updateButton('back', 'onclick', 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getBackJobUrl() . '\')');
        }
        else{
            $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save And Exit'));
        }

        $this->_addButton('addorder', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save and Create New Job'),
            'class' => 'save create-new-job',
            'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\'' . $this->getSaveAndAddJobUrl() . '\')',
        ), 100);

        $this->_addButton('addcomplaint', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save and Create New Complaint'),
            'class' => 'save create-new-complaint',
            'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\'' . $this->getSaveAndAddComplaintUrl() . '\')',
        ), 101);

        if (!Mage::registry('current_customer')->isDeleteable()) {
            $this->_removeButton('delete');
        }

        $admin_user = Mage::helper('sales')->getCurrentAdmin(true);

        if($admin_user && $admin_user->getRoleInfo() && $admin_user->getRoleInfo()->getId() != 7){
            $this->_removeButton('addorder');
            $this->_removeButton('addcomplaint');
            $this->_removeButton('delete');
            $this->_removeButton('save');

            $this->_removeButton('save_and_continue');
            $this->_removeButton('saveAndContinueEdit');
            $this->_removeButton('save_and_edit_button');
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        if (!Mage::registry('current_customer')->isReadonly()) {
            $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->_getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\')',
                'class'     => 'save'
            ), 10);
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array(
            '_current'  => true,
            'back'      => 'edit',
            'tab'       => '{{tab_id}}'
        ));
    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your  __construct function.

```
$this->_removeButton("saveandcontinue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
$this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->_getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\')',
                'class'     => 'save'
            ), 10);
```

from your _prepareLayout function it will start working.